# SVG Patch is not cleared

Tags: javascript, svg

Thanks for advance,
i have used the below code with (MoveTo Lineto),

```
<svg height="200" width="500">
      <path fill='none' stroke-width="30" stroke="black" d="M 100 63.125 L 254 63.125 L 254 117.5 L 418 117.5"/>
 </svg>
```

it's shown fine but when i use same with(MoveTo Lineto MoveTo)

```
<svg height="200" width="500">
      <path fill='none' stroke-width="30" stroke="black" d="M 100 63.125 L 254 63.125 L 254 117.5 M 254 117.5 L 418 117.5">
</svg>
```

.5 pixel is vary check the attached image.

[image]

Why that difference? and how to solve?
Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/3t8rspd1/1/

Comment: change the stroke width to, say 30 - then with a value of 30, see that the x position has to be moved left by 15 to line up properly ... with stroke width 40, that needs a move of 20 left ... hopefully that will be enough to give you an aha moment, because I can't really put into words what is obvious if you draw things like this by hand on some grid paper for example ... the fact that you stop and start the path is the key

Comment: And for the solution : continue using `lineTo`.

Comment: @Kaiido i need to use M L M because of some internal calculation..

Comment: I can't see why, but then just calculate the moveTo's position relative to the stroke-width (`required_center_position - (strokeWidth/2)`)

Comment: Learn about `stroke-linecap` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap and `stroke-linejoin`

Comment: @AlexeyTen `linejoin` won't help with a moveTo, and while `stroke-linecap="rounded"` could hide the imperfection, it will just be hidden and furthermore, you can't set it for only one end of the path.

Comment: @Kaiido, that's not an imperfection. That's just lack of understanding how stroke works and difference between continuous and discontinuous lines.

Comment: @AlexeyTen that becomes an imperfection when you try to hide it instead of fixing it. Also, again, OP never said he wanted rounded cap so why should he have those for the rest of his path?

Comment: Actually, I meant `square` caps. And calculation that he choose as an answers suggest, that he just wants second image to be similar to first one.

Comment: Anyway, the main idea of my link to learn about different kinds of caps

Comment: @AlexeyTen but my point is that using line-cap it won't be similar to the first one anymore : http://jsfiddle.net/jtj21ach/ red is OP's one, blue is your one, green is accepted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please minus the half the stroke width from x position. 
you will get the correct path.
eg. if stroke width is 20 mean minus the 10 from second MoveTo.

**calculation** 254-(storkeWidth/2) = 244. if strokeWidth is 20.

```
<svg height="200" width="500">
  <path fill='none' stroke-width="20" stroke="black" d="M 100 63.125 L 254 63.125 L 254 117.5 M 244 117.5 L 418 117.5"/>
</svg>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t8rspd1/3/)

Answer (score 0):

[stroke-linejoin](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeLinejoinProperty)

```
<svg height="200" width="500">
  <path fill='none' stroke-width="30" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="black" d="M 100 63.125 L 254 63.125 L 254 117.5 L 418 117.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You are not using moveTo... Your code without the stroke-linejoin will do just fine...